# How to correctly delete all images uploaded using sonata-media-bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I have uploaded some images using the sonata-media-bundle, as suggested [here](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/2-2/doc/reference/usage.html)

```php
$media = new Media;
$media->setBinaryContent($file->getRealPath());
$media->setContext('myContext'); 
$media->setProviderName('sonata.media.provider.image');
$mediaManager->save($media);
```

Previous code creates the media correctly all files (according to context config) and db registry. Now what I did to delete the media is calling like this:

```
$media = $mediaManager->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
$mediaManager->delete($media)
```

It correctly deletes the media data from database but not from the configured fileSystem, there are still some images associated to the uploaded media. I'm planning using the S3 filesystem so I need to delete all with the same framework

the most relevant of my sonata configuration (using the suggested too) is like this:

`sonata_media:
    default_context: default
    db_driver: doctrine_orm
    class:
        media: MyApp\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
        gallery: MyApp\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
        gallery_has_media: MyApp\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
    contexts:
        default:
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.youtube
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file
            formats:
                small: { width: 200, quality: 77}
        myContext:
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.image
            formats:
                normal: { width: 350, quality: 75}
                tmb: { width: 100, quality: 75}
    filesystem:
        local:
            directory: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media
            create:    false`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to correctly delete all media related to the uploaded file, one has to use the appropiate provider:

from the sonata media [documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/2-2/doc/reference/creating_a_provider_class.html)

> A provider class is responsible for handling common things related to a media asset:
>
> - thumbnails
> - path
> - editing the media with a form
> - storing the media information (metadata)

So the code would look like:

```
$media = $mediaManager->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
//assuming you have access through $this->get to the service container
$provider = $this->get($media->getProviderName());
$provider->removeThumbnails($media);
$mediaManager->delete($media)
```