# Sonata Media Bundle delete image programmatically

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

It seems that there is no documentation about how to delete images programmatically with [Sonata Media Bundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/3-x/doc/index.html).

I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942476/how-to-correctly-delete-all-images-uploaded-using-sonata-media-bundle) saying that you need to call `delete` on the media manager.

Here is my mapping:

```
/**
 * @var Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
protected $image;
```

And this is the code I use to delete:

```
$this->mediaManager = $this->getContainer()->get('sonata.media.manager.media');
$previousMedia = $myEntity->getImage();
$provider = $this->getContainer()->get($previousMedia->getProviderName());
$provider->removeThumbnails($previousMedia);
$this->mediaManager->delete($previousMedia);
```

The association is correctly remove (the entity `image` field is now `null`) but on my gallery the object still exists and looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?